# AWS AppConfig for app critical config concerns about reliability

Tags: aws-app-config

I'm considering using AWS AppConfig to push an IP white list to an ECS sidecar container.

The sidecar container must retrieve the IP white list from AppConfig on container startup.  If it failed, the main web app would be inaccessible.

My concern is that if there are any issues with AppConfig - it may cause a fleet of web apps to fail.

Is AppConfig as reliable as an RDS connection or the instance metadata endpoint?

Regarding latency & reliability, would AppConfig be preferable to a fleet of IP filter instances pulling config directly from an s3 bucket?